# Dequeues in Java

Tags: java, deque

I'm having trouble with fully implementing the enqueue and dequeue portion. Here's the result I'm trying to get:

```
DEQUE TESTING

The size of the deque is: 3

The deque contains:

4 9 8 

4

8

9

1

11

The size of the deque is: 2

The deque contains:


11 1
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
DEQUE TESTING
The size of the deque is: 3
The deque contains:
 4 9 8
4
null
null
null
null
The size of the deque is: 0
The deque contains:
```

So, it's only printing up to a certain point. I've went through my code several times (actually a lot) in an attempt to correct this issue, but I can't determine where the problem lies. I have a feeling its something minor that needs to be changed.

Here is my code:

```
public class Murray_A06Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedDeque<Integer> deque = new LinkedDeque<Integer>();

        System.out.println("DEQUE TESTING");

        deque.enqueueBack(3);
        deque.enqueueBack(7);
        deque.enqueueBack(4);
        deque.dequeueFront();        
        deque.enqueueBack(9);
        deque.enqueueBack(8);
        deque.dequeueFront();

        System.out.println("The size of the deque is: " + deque.size());
        System.out.println("The deque contains:\n" + deque.toString());   

        System.out.println(deque.dequeueFront());        

        deque.enqueueFront(1);
        deque.enqueueFront(11);                         
        deque.enqueueFront(3);                 
        deque.enqueueFront(5);         

        System.out.println(deque.dequeueBack());
        System.out.println(deque.dequeueBack());        
        System.out.println(deque.last());                

        deque.dequeueFront();
        deque.dequeueFront();        

        System.out.println(deque.first());        
        System.out.println("The size of the deque is: " + deque.size());
        System.out.println("The deque contains:\n" + deque.toString());            

    } // End of main method

public static class LinkedDeque<T> implements DequeADT<T> {

    private int count; 
    private LinearDoubleNode<T> firstNode, lastNode;

// constructor
    public LinkedDeque(){

        count = 0;
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode = null;

    } // end of constructor

// Beginning of enqueueFront
    public void enqueueFront(T element) {
        LinearDoubleNode newNode = new LinearDoubleNode();

        if(isEmpty()){
            lastNode = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else
            firstNode.setPrev(newNode);
        firstNode = newNode;
        count--;

    } // end of enqueFront

// Beginning of enqueueBack
    public void enqueueBack(T element) {
        LinearDoubleNode<T> node = new LinearDoubleNode<T>(element);

        if (isEmpty())
           firstNode = node;
        else
            lastNode.setNext(node);

        lastNode = node;
        count++;

    } // end of enqueueBack

// Beginning of dequeueFront
    public T dequeueFront() {

        T front = null;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            front = firstNode.getElement();
            firstNode = firstNode.getNext();
            count--;

            if (firstNode == null) {
                lastNode = null;
            }
            else 
                firstNode.setPrev(firstNode);
        }
        return front;

    } // end of dequeueFront

// Beginning of dequeueBack
    public T dequeueBack() {

        T back = null;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            back = lastNode.getElement();
            lastNode = lastNode.getPrev();

            if (lastNode == null) {
                firstNode = null;
            }
            else 
                lastNode.setNext(null);
        }
        return back;

    } // end of dequeueBack()

    public T first() {
        return firstNode.getElement();
    }

    public T last() {
        return lastNode.getElement();
    }

// Beginning of isEmpty()           
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        if (count == 0) {
            return true;
        }       
        else 
            return false;

    } // End of isEmpty()

// Beginning of size()          
    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

 // Begin of toString() method          
    public String toString() {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            return " ";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        LinearDoubleNode<T> next = firstNode;

        while(next != null){
            sb.append(" ").append(next.getElement());
            next = next.getNext();
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } // End of toString()

  } // End of LinkedDeque

} // End of class header
```

Comment: Hint: (1) `count--` in `enqueueFront` doesn't make any sense. (2) In both `enqueue`, you need to call both `setPrev` and `setNext`, because it's a doubly-linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the previous and the elements. Also you had some errors when incrementing the count. And be caucios about some exceptions which are not thrown. Nevertheless, it should be straightforward now. You have below working code with the required output:

```
  public static class LinkedDeque<T> {

        private int count;
        private LinearDoubleNode<T> firstNode, lastNode;

        // constructor
        public LinkedDeque(){

            count = 0;
            firstNode = null;
            lastNode = null;

        } // end of constructor

        // Beginning of enqueueFront
        public void enqueueFront(T element) {
            LinearDoubleNode newNode = new LinearDoubleNode();
            newNode.setElement(element);
            if(isEmpty()){

                lastNode = newNode;
                firstNode = newNode;
            }
            else {
                LinearDoubleNode second=firstNode;
                firstNode=newNode;
                firstNode.setNext(second);
                second.setPrev(firstNode);
               // firstNode.setPrev(newNode);

            }

            count++;

        } // end of enqueFront

        // Beginning of enqueueBack
        public void enqueueBack(T element) {
            if (element==null) throw  new NullPointerException("cannot add null to the list");

            LinearDoubleNode<T> node = new LinearDoubleNode<T>(element);
            node.setElement(element);
            if (isEmpty()){
                firstNode = node;
                lastNode=node;}
            else{
                LinearDoubleNode<T> before=lastNode;
                lastNode=node;
                before.setNext(lastNode);
                lastNode.setPrev(before);
            }


            count++;

        } // end of enqueueBack

        // Beginning of dequeueFront
        public T dequeueFront() {

            T front = null;
            if (count==1){
                front=firstNode.getElement();
                firstNode=null;
                lastNode=null;
                count--;
            }
            else if (!isEmpty()) {
                count--;
                front = firstNode.getElement();
                firstNode = firstNode.getNext();
            }

            return front;

        } // end of dequeueFront

        // Beginning of dequeueBack
        public T dequeueBack() {

            T back = null;
            if (count==1){
                back = lastNode.getElement();
                lastNode = null;
                firstNode = null;
                count--;
            }
             else if (!isEmpty()) {
                count--;
                back = lastNode.getElement();
                lastNode = lastNode.getPrev();
                lastNode.setNext(null);
            }
            return back;

        } // end of dequeueBack()

        public T first() {
            return firstNode.getElement();
        }

        public T last() {
            return lastNode.getElement();
        }

        // Beginning of isEmpty()
        public boolean isEmpty() {

            return count==0;

        } // End of isEmpty()

        // Beginning of size()
        public int size() {
            return count;
        }

        // Begin of toString() method
        public String toString() {

            if (isEmpty()) {
                return " ";
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            LinearDoubleNode<T> next = firstNode;

            while(next != null){
                sb.append(" ").append(next.getElement());
                next = next.getNext();
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } // End of toString()

    } // End of LinkedDeque

} // End of class header

    DEQUE TESTING
The size of the deque is: 3
The deque contains:
 4 9 8
4
8
9
1
11
The size of the deque is: 2
The deque contains:
 11 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was wrong in that it required a little more than a minor adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of a doubly-linked list is that you have to maintain *two* links when you add an element. This is your code:

```
public void enqueueFront(T element) {
    LinearDoubleNode newNode = new LinearDoubleNode();

    if(isEmpty()){
        lastNode = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
        firstNode.setPrev(newNode);
    firstNode = newNode;
    count--;

} // end of enqueFront
```

First, you never put the value of your element into the new Node.

Second, the queue should look like

```
A ⇆ B ⇆ C
```

But let's see how you add an "A" when you have only a "B" in the queue. Your `firstNode` is the "B", and you set its `prev` with `setPrev` to point to your "A".

```
A ← B
```

But you do not link back from the new "A" to "B". This means that when you need to look at the queue from the front side, it seems to have only one element - A doesn't have a "next"!

Your `else` clause should be:

```
    else {
        firstNode.setPrev(newNode);
        newNode.setNext(firstNode);
    }
```

And then you'll be able to traverse the list from both sides. The same logic should be applied to your `enqueueBack` as well.

Now, your dequeue logic:

```
public T dequeueFront() {

    T front = null;
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        front = firstNode.getElement();
        firstNode = firstNode.getNext();
        count--;

        if (firstNode == null) {
            lastNode = null;
        }
        else 
            firstNode.setPrev(firstNode);
    }
    return front;

}
```

Now, after you dequeue, you set the of the new firstNode to itself. This means you might have an infinite loop. After you do this once, if you try to walk the "prev" link by dequeuing  from the back, you'll just get the same node again and again. The backlink should be set to `null` (which you do properly in `dequeueBack`, by the way).